# How can I track a C2100 (illegal indirection) or C2675 error in a large visual studio project?

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on a very large project that is being built in visual studio 2019. Using this newer version of the compiler, we found two errors crop up in xutility - C2100 (illegal indirection) and C2675 (unary++ operator not defined). They did not show up before when compiled in Linux under a different chain.

To be clear: Xutility (which is part of Visual Studio/MSVCC) is of course not the actual broken code. It's just somehow, the broken code that we have written is getting compiled into using Xutility template code, which then is where the error shows up. So double clicking the error only takes me to xutility, not the root of the problem.

Now, this is a huge project with many large third-party libraries. Does Visual Studio have *any way* of telling me what source file the error *actually* occurred in? (Or, at least, the first occurrence?)

If I can't find the source file responsible it will be impossible to fix.

Comment: Double-clicking the error message in the Output window should take you to the source.

Comment: Double clicking the error only takes me to Xutility. Xutility itself is a part of visual studio and the MSVCC - it's not the broken code. It's just that something *else* in the code is doing illegal indirection, which gets compiled into using this xutility code by the MSVCC, which then has the error. See the problem?

Comment: Maybe you need to change the error 'tolerance' settings? This could be that Xutility doesn't conform to the default standards used by the latest VS release. (Did it work with an earlier version?) There's a "Conformance Mode" switch in project properties/C++/language.